# vaadin responsive not working properly

Tags: java, html, css, responsive-design, vaadin8

I'm using new Version of Vaadin which is 8.0.6

if I open my window on  width-range~="1400px-"  and go down to  width-range~="0px-760px", responsive css properties works fine, but not on the other way, If open the window on  width-range~="0px-760px" and go to width-range~="1200px-" nothing happens.

My observations showed that when the window is minimized vaadin injects the property "width-range=[...]" into HTML code to make it responsive. But when the window is maximized the property "width-range=[...]" stay here consequently this disrupts the display.

How can i do to update or delete the property "width-range=[...]" when I make the width window bigger?

Comment: can you improve your question by adding relative code needed to recreate your issue?

Comment: this docs here might help you, https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-responsive.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and was able to fix it by giving the responsive layout a width:

```
    CssLayout layout = new CssLayout();
    layout.setWidth("100%");
    layout.addStyleName("responsive");
    layout.setResponsive(true);
```